# Matlab '&&' error

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, logic

i need help about my code.
i cant figure out what im doing wrong.
here is the criterias i try to code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjHxk.jpg)
and data file ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByYia_19kCK4SXJMT2Q2ZHJHLVU/view?usp=sharing )
so i code this for solve it. but code always say 'NS' and i want "regime" data respect my table.
thx for all who try to help

```
data = xlsread('Data.xls');
PP=data(:,2);
TP=data(:,4);
BP=data(:,6);
region={ };

for i=1:length(data)

if PP(i)>=52 && 35>=TP(i);
region{i}='NF';
elseif 40<=PP(i) & PP(i)<52 & (TP(i)<=20);
region{i}='NS';
elseif (40>PP(i)) && (BP(i)>=45) && TP(i)<=20;
region{i}='SS';
elseif (PP(i)<=20) && (45<=BP(i)) && (TP(i)<=40);
region{i}='SS';
elseif (PP(i)<=20) && (40<=TP(i) && TP(i)<=52) ;
region{i}='TS';
elseif (PP(i) <=32) && (TP(i)>=52);
region{i}='NF';
else 
region{i}='UN';
end

end
```

Comment: You can also use the [matlab debugger](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to understand why your code is behaving the way it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your P_plunge is only between 40 & 52. It makes perfect sense that they all fall under NS.

Perhaps you might want to use column 1 for the data?

Also use && instead of &.

Good luck!